# What is the prepositional phrase “with confidence” modifying?

Tags: grammar, subjects

> "Our vision goes beyond the familiar, with confidence to step into new adventures that help our environment."

Is this sentence grammatical or is there something missing? I feel like the phrase "..., with confidence ..." isn't attached to a proper subject and so it doesn't sound very solid, but I could be overthinking it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it happens, the "adverb of manner" element ***with confidence*** here is itself further modified by the "adverb of purpose" ***to step into new adventures that help our environment***. We can remove that syntactically optional second element to focus on the first...

> 1: *Our vision goes beyond the familiar, with confidence.*
> 2: *With confidence, our vision goes beyond the familiar.*
> 3: *Our vision goes with confidence beyond the familiar.*
> 4: *Our vision with confidence goes beyond the familiar.*

...which are all syntactically valid and mean the same thing. It's just that #3 (and even more so #4) are stylistically a bit awkward.

Hopefully this makes it clear that ***with confidence*** adverbially modifies the primary verb ***goes***. But it might more naturally be interpreted as a "whole sentence adverb" (my versions #1 & #2) modifying the entire assertion *Our vision goes beyond the familiar to step into new adventures that help our environment.*

Comment: I agree. The entire phrase after the comma could also be a single adverbial phrase, modifying "goes". "Our vision goes beyond the familiar, and it does so with the confidence to step into new adventures". If I had meant your version I would have put a second comma after "confidence", but I recognize that not everyone would do that

Comment: I certainly can't disagree with anything you say there! I kinda thought I'd covered all bases by pointing out that (leading *or* trailing) "with confidence" could modify the entire assertion rather than any specific part of it. But to be honest, I think any apparent *semantic* difference is just an artifact of how English adverbials work - at the end of the day, all three of the "syntactic deconstructions" we've identified just net down to a single real-world meaning, imho.

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaborate answer. This makes perfect sense. @FumbleFingers

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that "vision" doesn't "step"; it "sees."

> "Our vision goes beyond the familiar, with confidence to see into new
> adventures that help our environment."

Comment: It also "goes". Must be at least 20/20.

Comment: "vision" doesn't "see". The one having vision sees.